# Find $x+y+z$ given that $x^{y^z} \cdot y^{z^x} \cdot z^{x^y} = 3xyz$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the value of $x+y+z$ (Given that $x,y,z \in \mathbb Z^+$) if $$x^{y^z} \cdot y^{z^x} \cdot z^{x^y} = 3xyz.$$

Any hint or idea will be very helpful, I tried my best but didn't get any approach.

Comment: When you say "(x^y^z)," do you mean $x^{(y^z)}$ or $(x^y)^z$?

Comment: Plus, if you're going to ask questions here, learning MathJax is a good idea. Here's a tutorial - https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Ishan deo thanks brother

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose at least one of $x,y,z$ is $=1$. By cyclic symmetry, we may assume $z=1$. Then the equation becomes
$$x^yy=3xy,$$
or,
$$x^{y-1}=3 $$
from which we read off the solution $$\tag1 x=3,\quad y=2,\quad z=1.$$

Remains the case that each of $x,y,z$ is $\ge 2$. But then 
$$x^{y^z}y^{z^x}z^{x^y}\ge x^4y^4z^4\ge 8x8y8z>3xyz. $$
We conclude that $(1)$ and the cyclic  permutations thereof are the only solutions in positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

One can directly simplify the equation to $x^{y^z-1} y^{z^x-1} z^{y^x-1} = 3$. As all 3 factors are positive integers, and 3 is prime, two of them have to be one, and one of them 3. Take without loss of generality that $x^{y^z-1} = 1$, $y^{z^x-1}=1$ and $z^{y^x-1} = 3$. Then $z=3$ and $y^x-1=1$ because the only way to write $3$ as a power is $3^1$. Then follows $y^x=2$, and by consequence, $y=2$ and $x=1$. By symmetry, there are two other solutions, if we cyclically permute them. So all solution are:

$x=3$ and $y=2$ and $z=1$

$x=1$ and $y=3$ and $z=2$

$x=2$ and $y=1$ and $z=3$